# How to put different JSON objects in Scrollview?

Tags: android, json, scrollview

**I am fetching JSON data as below**

```
           JsonObjectRequest jor = new  JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()  {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try{

                        JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("results");

                        for(int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                            int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
                            String url = jsonObject.getString("resLink");
                            String resType= jsonObject.getString("resType");
                            String name = jsonObject.getString("resName");

                            data += "ResType= "+resType  +" \n URl= "+ url +" \n  id = "+ id + "\n Name = "+ name+"\n\n\n" ;
                           // data +=videoUrl+url;

                        }

                        output.setText(data);


                    }catch(JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
```

*I am simply fetching JSON data and showing it in the text view.What I need is to display those in horizontal scroll view according to the resType.Means all restype as "image" will be in image scroll view and videos will be in video scroll view in the same screen*

Comment: Hello from your code i can say that, data += "ResType= "+resType  +" \n URl= "+ url +" \n  id = "+ id + "\n Name = "+ name+"\n\n\n" ; will add all the data in the data string, you are not distinguish all the data based on your resource type, try to get four different String of data and distinguish all the data and add them in each individual and show them in the textview.

Comment: put them as you are doing for simple JSON with other views.

Comment: okay @Silvans   let me try...

Comment: Now I am getting data in different text view.But there is a lot of data so do I have to use listview to show the data in scroll view

Comment: Create two string : dataImage ,dataVideo .As you extract the resType string , do a test if it match video or image resources .Then add the whole thing to dataImage or dataVideo according to the type. Now you need just to show dataImage and dataVideo into two differnts views.

Answer (score 0):

First add a model like this

```
    /**
     * Created by waqas.ali on 3/4/2016.
     */
    public class MyModel {
    String name;
    String resType;
    String url;
    int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getResType() {
        return resType;
    }
    public void setResType(String resType) {
        this.resType = resType;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Then replace your code as

```
    JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("results");
    List<MyModel> myModelList = new ArrayList<MyModel>;
    for(int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++){

    JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
    MyModel mymodel=new MyModel();
    mymodel.id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
    mymodel.url = jsonObject.getString("resLink");
    mymodel.resType= jsonObject.getString("resType");
    mymodel.name = jsonObject.getString("resName");

    myModelList.add(mymodel);

    }
```

Then finally pass myModelList to your adapter.

This will give you idea how to go.

Comment: Can you check this line showing compile time error   List<MyModel> myModelList = new ArrayList<MyModel>;

Comment: Sorry its like that List<MyModel> myModelList =new ArrayList<MyModel>();

Comment: Do I have to override any method to fetch data or just fetch the data  like this output.getText(myModelList.get(i).getResType());

Comment: MyModel mymodel=myModelList.get(i);
then you will set values like this
youtTextView.setText().mymodel.getId();
youtTextView.setText().mymodel.geurl();

Comment: Is there anything I have to add youtTextView.setText(...anythig..).mymodel.getId();